# Is possible to open file explorer and attach the file selected to outlook and send it in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script that will allow me to send a selected file from Explorer using Powershell. I did create the below but everytime I use is it will not pickup any file I select and will send the email without any attachment. Can anyone help?

I do not like to enter the path straight in the script as the files I use might be in a different folder or with a different name, that's why I'd like to select it manual (and of course other people will be using it to facilitate our work)

```
write-host "Attaching downloaded Security Manual"

#Promting for mail address and if file has been downloaded
$user= read-host -Prompt "Enter user email address";
$sm= read-host -Prompt "Did you download the signed Survey? (y/n)";

#if statement, if the answer will be 'y' it will send do the below, if 'n' it will stop the script as it is
if ($sm -eq "y")
{
$ref= read-host -Prompt "Enter ticker ref number";

#Opening explorer and select the file
$myFile = "$home\"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Split-Path $myFile -Parent 
$OpenFileDialog.FileName = Split-path $myfile -leaf
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

#open outlook and send the email
$ol= New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$mail= $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.recipients.Add("$user")
$mail.subject="$ref"
$mail.Attachments("$myFile")
$mail.send()
}
```

There is no error message when I run it but I can see in my inbox and outbox that the mail sent is just without any attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly had it.

```
#Opening explorer and select the file
$myFile = "$home\"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = Split-Path $myFile -Parent
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$Attachment = $OpenFileDialog.filename

#open outlook and send the email
$ol= New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$mail= $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.recipients.Add("$user")
$mail.subject="$ref"
$mail.Attachments.add("$Attachment")
$mail.send()
```

This will attach the document you put into the `OpenFileDialog` box.
You can ignore using the `$Attachment` variable and call the `$OpenFileDialog.filename` directly in the `$mail.Attachments.add($OpenFileDialog.filename)`, but for re-usability I have created its own variable.

EDIT: Forgot the `.add` method on the `$mail.Attachments`

Comment: Hi Drew, I will try today :) and if will work I'll request the closure of the question, thanks a lot. Will hear you later!

Comment: I did try that but unfortunately still doesn't attach anything to the email sent :( I used the changes and also tried to copy paste your one just in case I missed come lines or letters, nothing did work :(

Comment: What happens when you check `$Attachment`? Is it a valid file path?

Comment: As far as I could see wasn't giving any error in the coding or running the script. I've tried either with a .txt or .pdf document but didn't work either, the email sent was just without any attachments. I also tried to don't use the variable as you suggested I could ignore it (fair enough, it's just to make easier if I wanted to reuse the command) but as expecting gave the same result. Wonder if it just doesn't pick any files, like it shows me the explorer and let me select but doesn't technically pick that file and use afterwards for the attachment.

Comment: I completely overlooked a fundamental part. See updated answer.

Comment: Not sure how I did miss that small piece too lol, it's working anyway :D thanks a lot Drew!